# What is the difference between these two relays?

Tags: dc, relay

1- DC12V Coil Power Relay 10A [DPDT LY2NJ HH62P HHC68A-2Z With Socket Base](http://www.ebay.com/itm/121034195696)

2- Amico 12V DC Coil Power Relay [DPDT LY2NJ HH62P-L JQX-13F 10A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0087ZTEBG) With PTF08A Socket Base

First assumption is that they are the same thing, but before I jumped to a conclusion I wanted to get some clarification.

If these are different what makes them different?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture there doesn't show it very clearly at all, but the "-L" suffix specifies that [there should be an LED indicator on the coil contacts](http://www.fujielectric.co.jp/fcs/eng/product/control/pdf/DEC1903a_P037_040.pdf) to indicate relay activation.

Comment: Is that the only difference between the two?

Comment: Based on the product descriptions and the datasheet, yes.

Comment: Okay. I guess I was getting confused by the base product numbers, two different manufacturers. Awesome, thanks. I was trying to find the product sheet for the amazon one but couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: Most Chinese "knock-offs" don't have a datasheet anywhere, but they're usually *reasonably* adherent to the originals.

Comment: So if you were picking one, disregarding price which would you choose?

Comment: In safety-related applications I'd use the one with an indicator. Otherwise, it usually wouldn't matter.